# Searching and Deleting specific characters in a string

Tags: java, string, replace, char

I'm trying to delete non-alphabetic and non-numberic characters from user input (String). I'm not sure why but when I run the code I get a "java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: null(in java.util.regex.Pattern) error on the line that says

```
 a.replaceAll(ch , "");
```

I'm pretty new to java, so I may have made a blatant mistake but I'm not sure..

the numbers used in the for loop are character values of non-alphabetic or non-numeric characters.

Here's the full code for this

```
public static String helper(String a)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
    {

        char c = (char)i;
        String ch = String.valueOf(c);
        a.replaceAll(ch , "");
    }
    for(int i = 91; i < 97; i++)
    {
        char c = (char)i;
        String ch = String.valueOf(c);
        a.replaceAll(ch , "");
    }
    for(int i = 123; i <= 127; i++)
    {
        char c = (char)i;
        String ch = String.valueOf(c);
        a.replaceAll(ch , "");
    } 
    return a;
}
```

Comment: **`String` is immutable!** Also, read the javadoc of the methods you attempt to use.

Comment: if you replace so many times instead of using String try it with StringBuilder

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure why but when I run the code I get a "java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException"

You get this error because the first parameter of `replaceAll` is treated as a regular expression. If `ch` happens to be a metacharacter, you may get an error or unexpected behavior. If you do not want to use regular expression behavior, use `replace` method, which treats the first parameter as a "plain" `String`.

Also note that calling `a.replaceAll(ch , "");` and ignoring its return value is useless: strings in Java are immutable, so you need to assign the result back to `a` in order for the operation to have any effect:

```
a = a.replace(ch , "");
```

Comment: would fixing it to 
            char c = (char)i;
            a = a.replace(String.valueOf(c) , "");

do the trick?

Comment: @user3164890 Yes, it should. Try it out to confirm that it works on your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried like this in `replaceAll` to remove the non-numeric and non-alphabetic characters

```
yourString= yourString.replaceAll("[^0-9A-Za-z]","");
```